# "Bootstrap-slider.js" mouse events are not working on touchscreen devices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap-slider.js (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider) mouse events are not working on touchscreen devices.

When I have a mouse only device, mouse event is working well and when I have a touchscreen device with no mouse, all touch events are working.

I have a touchscreen laptop with mouse, so when I move the slider with touch, it is working well, but when I move the slider with mouse is not working.

There is no error in the console.

Finally I have fixed the problem by removing the "this.touchCapable" and bind both touch and mouse events (touchmove, touchstart, touchend, mousedown, mousemove and mouseup).

The code below is my change in "Bootstrap-slider.js", The slider is working good in all 3 scenarios (touchscreen, mouse only, touchscreen with mouse).

```
//if (typeof Modernizr !== 'undefined' && Modernizr.touch) {
        //    this.touchCapable = true;
//}

//if (this.touchCapable) {
// Touch: Bind touch events:
this.picker.on({
    touchstart: $.proxy(this.mousedown, this)
});
//} else {
this.picker.on({
    mousedown: $.proxy(this.mousedown, this)
});
//}

//if (this.touchCapable && ev.type === 'touchstart') {
if (ev.type == "touchmove" || ev.type == "touchstart" || ev.type == "touchend") {
     ev = ev.originalEvent;
}

//if (this.touchCapable) {
if (ev.type == "touchmove" || ev.type == "touchstart" || ev.type == "touchend") {
    // Touch: Bind touch events:
    $(document).on({
         touchmove: $.proxy(this.mousemove, this),
         touchend: $.proxy(this.mouseup, this)
    });} else {
    $(document).on({
         mousemove: $.proxy(this.mousemove, this),
         mouseup: $.proxy(this.mouseup, this)
     });
   }

// Touch: Get the original event:
//if (this.touchCapable && ev.type === 'touchmove') {
if (ev.type == "touchmove" || ev.type == "touchstart" || ev.type == "touchend") {
    ev = ev.originalEvent;
}

//if (this.touchCapable) {
if (ev.type == "touchmove" || ev.type == "touchstart" || ev.type == "touchend") {
    // Touch: Bind touch events:
    $(document).off({
          touchmove: this.mousemove,
          touchend: this.mouseup
     });} else {
     $(document).off({
         mousemove: this.mousemove,
         mouseup: this.mouseup
     });
}

//if (this.touchCapable) {
if (ev.type == "touchmove" || ev.type == "touchstart" || ev.type == "touchend") {
    ev = ev.touches[0];
}
```

Comment: Define "not working"? Errors in the console? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: There is no error in the console. If upgrading your Chrome you can see slide is not working. When I remove modernizr.js the slider working correctly.

Comment: I have fixed my problem by removing the "this.touchCapable" and binding touchstart and mousedown together.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [jQuery UI Touch Punch plugin](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to fire all the touch events corresponding to their mouse events.

Thanks,
varun.